# ¿Equivalente de canvas en PixiJS?

Tags: canvas, pixijs

¿Cómo se realiza el siguiente código en PixiJS? He intentado viendo documentación y varias cosas, pero no hay mucho en español.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.font = "20px Ubuntu";
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillText("Pixi",10,30,200);
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas width="50%;" height="50%;" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En esta página de la [documentación de PixiJS](http://pixijs.github.io/examples/#/basics/text.js) puedes ver cómo se trabaja con el texto y tienen un pequeño snippet interactivo que te permite jugar con los valores y ver cómo funcionarían con diferentes formatos.

La idea es que puedes crear texto como el que tienes en el `canvas` usando el método `Text`, que toma como primer parámetro la cadena que quieres escribir, y como segundo parámetro le puedes pasar opcionalmente estilos para ese texto. En [esta otra página](http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.TextStyle.html) puedes ver los parámetros, los que vas a necesitar son estos:

- `fontFamily`: la fuente que quieres usar (en tu caso "Ubuntu").
- `fontSize`: el tamaño de la fuente en pixels (en tu caso 20).
- `fill`: el color del texto ("green")

Entonces el equivalente a lo que tienes en el `canvas` sería algo como esto:

```js
// aquí inicializamos una app de Pixi (y se creará un canvas)
var app = new PIXI.Application(400, 200, {backgroundColor: 0xffffff});
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

// definimos los estilos que tendrá el texto: color, fuente, tamaño, etc.
var estilos = new PIXI.TextStyle({
    fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
    fontSize: 20,
    fill: 'green',
    wordWrapWidth: 200
});

// creamos el texto en sí con los estilos, y después lo posicionamos
var texto = new PIXI.Text('Pixi', estilos);
texto.x = 10;
texto.y = 30;

// con el texto creado, lo agregamos a la aplicación que inicializamos al principio
app.stage.addChild(texto);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.5.3/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Y el tag de canvas no es utlizado? , ningún tag?

Comment: y porque al final app.stage.addChild(texto);

Comment: @EduardoSebastian la etiqueta de `canvas` no hace falta porque PixiJS la crea automáticamente por ti. Y al final tienes que hacer `app.stage.addChild(texto)` porque, aunque has creado el texto, aún no se ha añadido a la app/canvas. Ese paso es fundamental para que se vea el texto.