# No se dibuja el texto creado con PixiJS

Tags: canvas, pixijs

Intento dibujar el texto, pero no se dibuja, ¿por qué el error?

Éste es mi código:

```js
var a = document.getElementById("canvas");
var d = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(200,200,a);
var ctx = new PIXI.Graphics();

document.body.appendChild(d.view);

var es = new PIXI.TextStyle({fontFamily: 'monospace',fontSize: '20px',fill: 'blue'});
var t = new PIXI.Text('Probando.',es);
t.y = 50;
t.x = 50;

d.stage.addChild(d);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.5.3/pixi.min.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Eduardo. El fallo está en la linea `d.stage.addChild(d);`. Has mirado que devuelve `autoDetectRenderer`? De cualquier manera, has de explicar lo que intentas para poder entender lo que haces con tu codigo. Mira de nuevo [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tu preguntal. Un saludo

Comment: Ya lo resolví, estoy aprendiendo esto es nuevo para mi

Comment: Aún asi esperare una respuesta, ya que solo lo resolví con el método pero nose por que funciona de dicha manera

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Equivalente de canvas en PixiJS?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/89960/equivalente-de-canvas-en-pixijs)

Comment: No mariano, es d.render, asi que no veo el duplicado

Comment: @EduardoSebastian tenés razón en eso, pero como no estás usando `PIXI.Application()`, tal cual te respondieron en tu pregunta previa, no estás creando el contenedor (`stage`), por lo que deberías usar `Application()`, o crear el stage por código.

Comment: Eduardo, me alegra que lo solucionaras pero igualemnte la pregunta no es de buena calidad. Añade explicaciones y sigue la guia de [ask]. Además, tardaste 10 min en encontrar la solución... quizá la proxima vez deberías buscar más antes de publicar. Un saludo

Comment: Si lois6b, soy bastante ansioso para hacer preguntas, ya voy a mejorar eso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El código falla porque no hay ningún `stage` (contenedor). Se resuelve llamando a [`.Application()`](http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Application.html), como te respondieron en [tu pregunta previa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/89960/127).

De lo contrario, deberías crear un `stage` por código con [`PIXI.Container()`](http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Container.html),

```
var stage = new PIXI.Container();
```

Y luego llamando al `.render`.

Además, para usar un canvas ya existente, se tiene que pasar un objeto como tercer parámetro, con la propiedad:

```
{view: canvas}
```

Estos ejemplos están muy bien en la [documentación](http://pixijs.download/release/docs/index.html).
Te recomiendo leer el tutorial: [Learning Pixi](https://github.com/kittykatattack/learningPixi).

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(200,200,{view: canvas});

//Creamos un contenedor (stage)
var stage = new PIXI.Container();


//texto
var estilo = new PIXI.TextStyle({fontFamily: 'monospace',fontSize: '20px',fill: 'blue'});
var texto = new PIXI.Text('Probando.',estilo);
texto.y = 50;
texto.x = 50;

//texto al contenedor
stage.addChild(texto);

//contenedor al renderer
renderer.render(stage);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.5.3/pixi.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yo pondría unos nombres de variables más descriptivos. Por ejemplo canvas en vez de a. O ¿renderer? en vez de d. Por lo demás se entiende bien, incluso por mi que no se casi nada de pixijs, +1

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos voté para cerrar como duplicado y copié y pegué el código del autor (y sus variables) agregándole lo que faltaba... La idea era que esté cerrada, apuntando a la publicación donde se explica :-) Esto es más un comentario diciendo "*se hace igual que el duplicado que te respondieron hace unas horas, o agregando esta línea*"... Edité recién.